# Variable from VBA to VBScript

Tags: vba, excel, vbscript

I am working on VBA, from which I have to call a vbscript by passing some values.

Here is the code:

```
''VBA
'Below values are on different cells of Excel file which I am reading 
'into a global variable then pass it to vbscript.
'SFilename = VBscript file path
'QClogin = "abc"
'QCpassword = "abc"
'sDomain = "xyz"
'sProject = "xyz123"
'testPathALM = "Subject\xyz - Use it!\xyz_abc"
'QCurl = "http://xxx_yyy_zzz/qcbin/"
Set wshShell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")

Set proc = wshShell.exec("wscript " & SFilename & " " & QClogin & _
" " & "" & QCpassword & " " & "" & sDomain & " " & "" & sProject & _
" " & "" & testPathALM & " " & "" & QCurl & "")

''VBscript on some location
Dim strUserName, strPassword, strServer
strUserName = WScript.Arguments(0)  '"abc"
Msgbox "strUserName : " & strUserName
strPassword = WScript.Arguments(1)  '"abc"
Msgbox "strPassword : " & strPassword
strServer = WScript.Arguments(5)    '"http://xxx_yyy_zzz/qcbin/"
Msgbox "strServer : " & strServer

Dim strDomain, strProject, strRootNode
strDomain = WScript.Arguments(2)    '"xyz"
Msgbox "strDomain: " & strDomain
strProject = WScript.Arguments(3)   '"xyz123"
Msgbox "strProject: " & strProject
strRootNode = WScript.Arguments(4)  '"Subject\xyz - Use it!\xyz_abc"
Msgbox "strRootNode: " & strRootNode
```

Now, when I running the code, it is passing below values properly to vbscript:

```
QClogin = "abc"
QCpassword = "abc"
sDomain = "xyz"
sProject = "xyz123"
```

It is having issues with these:

```
testPathALM = "Subject\xyz - Use it!\xyz_abc"
QCurl = "http://xxx_yyy_zzz/qcbin/"
```

Now, wierd thing for me is, if I keep a cell empty for **"testPathALM"** which is having **"Subject\xyz - Use it!\xyz_abc"** as value, I am getting **"QCurl"** value properly in vbscript.

But, if I keep value **"Subject\xyz - Use it!\xyz_abc"** for **"testPathALM"**, then I am getting **"-"** for **strServer** which suppose to be **"QCurl"** value and **"Subject\xyz"** for **"strRootNode"** which supposed to be **"Subject\xyz - Use it!\xyz_abc"**.

I am unable to understand what is the issue here.

Thanks a ton in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Safer to quote all of your parameters:

```
Set wshShell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
Set proc = wshShell.exec("wscript """ & SFilename & """ """ & _
                         QClogin & """ """ & QCpassword & """ """ & _
                         sDomain & """ """ & sProject   & """ """ & _
                         testPathALM & """ """ & QCurl & """")
```

Try a debug.print to make sure it looks as it should...

Comment: + 1 you beat me to it :)